# SET default value of destination column if source column is NULL in postgresql8.4

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I am trying to insert data in a table and I don't want NULLs in that table instead I want it to use DEFAULT values for the columns in the target table

```
ex-
INSERT INTO dest_table
(id,
fname,
lname
)
SELECT
(
id,
fname,
lname
)
FROM src_table
```

DDL for destination table is

```
 CREATE TABLE dest_table (
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    fname varchar(55) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknown',
    lname varchar(55) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknown'
)
```

DDL for src table

```
 CREATE TABLE dest_table (
        id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        fname varchar(55),
        lname varchar(55),
        column1 int,
........ has multiple columns 
    )
```

Note- **I have large no of columns and I want to do this without using COALESCE for each and every column in my select statement.**

Comment: Adding the CREATE TABLE statement for the source table would be useful to understand the issue.

Comment: I dont understand how would it help but I just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you can use a conditional expression with CASE:

```
INSERT INTO dest_table (id, fname, lname )
    SELECT id, 
        CASE
            WHEN fname IS NULL THEN 'unknown'
            ELSE fname
            END,
        lname FROM src_table
```

Full example:

```
CREATE TABLE dest_table (
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    fname varchar(55) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknown',
    lname varchar(55) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknown'
);
INSERT INTO dest_table (fname,lname) VALUES ('alfa1','beta1');
INSERT INTO dest_table (fname,lname) VALUES ('alfa2','beta2');
INSERT INTO dest_table (fname,lname) VALUES ('alfa3','beta3');

CREATE TABLE src_table (
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    fname varchar(55),
    lname varchar(55),
    column1 int
);
INSERT INTO src_table (fname,lname) VALUES ('foo1','bar1');
INSERT INTO src_table (fname,lname) VALUES ('foo2','bar2');
INSERT INTO src_table (fname,lname) VALUES ('foo3','bar3');
INSERT INTO src_table (fname,lname) VALUES (null,'bar3');

INSERT INTO dest_table (id, fname, lname )
    SELECT id, 
        CASE
            WHEN fname IS NULL THEN 'unknown'
            ELSE fname
            END,
        lname FROM src_table
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But I am not really sure how is it different from using COALESCE? infact using CASE involves much more typing and like I specified in question I have large no of columns and I don't want to specifically put a condition on each column

Answer (score 0):

You might use a trigger, and verify the columns: every time it's NULL, replace it with the default value. NEW.* and OLD.* in pl/pgSQL hold the new and the old value in a trigger function.

Oh, and by the way, PG 8.4 is EOL for over a year now:
http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: I wish I could use trigger but unfortunately I am on Greenplum based on psql8.4 and in greenplum triggers are not allowed to update column values

Comment: Actually, Greenplum is based on PostgreSQL 8.2, not 8.4. But it got many features from later PG versions. Triggers are not officially supported in Greenplum, because you don't know if the trigger will be executed on the master or on the segment. This makes executing the trigger kind of unpredicatble.

Answer (score 0):

The OP said he did not want this as an answer, but I am listing it as an answer for the benefit of others who may be looking at this question:

```
INSERT INTO dest_table
(id,
fname,
lname
)
SELECT
(
id,
coalesce(fname, 'unknown') as fname,
coalesce(lname, 'unknown') as lname
)
FROM src_table
```